# Install on, install in, install to

Tags: verbs, prepositions, word-usage

When I say "programs to install on a new PC" it sounds alright to me, but I'm not sure if it's the correct usage. Which one of the following should I use?

- Programs to install **on** a new PC
- Programs to install **in** a new PC
- Programs to install **to** a new PC

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Programs get “installed *on*” a computer, not in one or to one.

However, you might also “install programs *in*” a particular directory.

You never install anything “to” anything else, though.

## At greater length

Although text and data alike go *ɪɴ* files and files go *ɪɴ*
directories, directories go *ᴏɴ* filesystems just as filesystems go
*ᴏɴ* disk partitions.

When you consider other storage media like memory
cards or magtapes or floppies, you find again that files and directories
go *ᴏɴ* those things, but that cards go *ɪɴ* their slots just like floppies go
*ɪɴ* their drives.

Yet tapes usually do **not** go *ɪɴ* their drives (unless they get stuck and tangled there), but rather are
mounted *ᴏɴ* them the same way that one mounts partitions (well, filesystems) *ᴏɴ* directories.

Comment: yes it is right but technically it is like that we install a program on a computer in a hard disk memory or in a folder.

Comment: @NetStarter I know that a “folder” is just a directory, but what’s a “hard disk memory”?

Comment: Programs would be installed TO a specific folder ON a hard disk or IN memory (eg. IN RAM).

Comment: @mattacular Sorry, but that is not right.  You cannot ever installing anything “to” anything else.

Comment: I think you could use *to* when describing the physical medium. *Install the software **to** disk.* *Save **to** cd-rom.*

Comment: Yeah, you can install to drives, folders, etc.

Comment: @mattacular If you say so.  In my world, it is the sign of a non-native speaker of English to say such things.  It makes no sense, and is never heard.

Comment: How about operating systems? E.g., on a guide to install some program "in Windows" or "on Windows"?

Comment: @Petaflop Probably not, not for me. One saves in a format not to a format.

Comment: @JuanA.Navarro I'd like to know too! That bothers me a lot. Did you fint the answer?

Answer (score 2):

I would personally use:

- 'install  on' when talking about a machine or device as a whole
- 'install to' when talking about the storage medium, eg, install to the C drive, or installing 'to' the cloud.
- 'install in' when talking about the folder or virtual directory.

On the opposite side of the coin, when you uninstall, people generally use 'uninstall from' rather than 'uninstall off' - as in "I uninstalled it from my machine".

Comment: Hi @myke black. Do you have any links to back this usage up?

Answer (score 1):

1. I walked up **to** the computer, and installed the latest version of WinZip **on** it, **in** the UTILS folder.
2. I walked up **to** the computer, and installed the latest version of WinZip **in** it, **on** the UTILS folder.
3. I walked up **to** the computer, and installed the latest version of WinZip **on** it, **on** the UTILS folder.
4. I walked up **to** the computer, and installed the latest version of WinZip **in** it, **in** the UTILS folder.

Of the above, only the first one sounds right. All the others sound off.

Look at it this way, when you put something on something else, it is visible. When you put something in something else, you cannot see it. When you install software, you will be able to see it, via an icon or whatever (yes I know there are exceptions). You will not necessarily know which folder you have put it in though.

Answer (score 1):

The most usual preposition would be *on* for the sentences above.

Both *in* and *to* are used for particular locations in a file-system. I'd favour *to*, and a simple google comparison seems to suggest that *to* is the most common, but *in* is also found.

You might also install a program *to* a computer, if you were doing it over a network, with the *to* reflecting the transfer from one computer *to* another one (or more than one).

Comment: What simple google did you perform?

Comment: Never mind, I did "install to a PC" and "install to a computer" (including the quotes) and they were indeed more popular than "install on a pc" etc. I have to say that surprised me, as the use of "to" sounds off to me. Perhaps its country specific?

Answer (score 0):

The most common usage is *on*. The reason for that is because you load softwares on top of the OS, which is a platform. *In* would be okay if the computer were a box and the software were a physical thing.