# Prepositions related to the Internet and computers

Tags: prepositions, internet

I am not a native speaker and prepositions are the part of speech that troubles me more. Checking different posts from the site I've learnt that you say:

**On** the Internet / **On** a website

**In** an email

**At** www.site.com

Could you please give me a hand and tell me, which prepositions normally will go with: *chat, file, document, forum, Skype, computer, folder*?
Thanks a lot

Comment: This is probably a better question for ELL, but a topic might be discussed *in* a chat, data is stored *in* a file, text is stored *in* a document, you may post *on* a forum (but others possible, depending on context), you work "on" a computer but may store your documents "in" a computer.  The documents are likely located "in" a folder.  Skype is a beast all to itself.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I think the question is too broad as currently written, and should show more research as explained in the [help], but some related questions include *[Install on/in/to](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/103542)*, *[Preposition for computer environments](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/152247)*, *[In/on one of the computers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152880)*, *[In/on the menu in software](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/74369)*, *[Copy on/in](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/70739)*, and *[on/in spreadsheet”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/75588)*

Comment: Thank you guys for your help! I've just realized now that there is the ELL community, I had no idea Stackexchange was such a huge site. I know the question is broad and prepositions will also depend on verbs used, but I wanted to know how it worked in general to point out where's the information. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

(I am) in a chat, but on chat

(It is) in a file, but on file

(It is) in a document

(I post / I saw it) on a forum

(I am) on Skype, but in a Skype call

(The file is) on my computer

(It is in) in a folder

The only time something would be in a computer would be if you were talking about the components of the computer like hard disk, memory, wiring, etc.

Comment: We also talk of something being *on file*. *I have the information on file at the office*.